# Hibernate Criteria aPI Multiselect

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql-9.2, java-ee-7, jpa-2.1

If I use Hibernate Criteria API like:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
Root<OneEntity> entityOneRoot = criteriaQuery.from(OneEntity.class);
Root<TwoEntity> entityTwoRoot = criteriaQuery.from(TwoEntity.class);
criteriaQuery.multiselect(OneEntity, TwoEntity);
```

Do I need to use EQUAL-restriction (as ON-restriction in SQL) for equaling IDs between both tables (entities)? Because of Cartesian product of both tables?

```
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(OneEntity.get("fk_id"), TwoEntity.get("id")));
```

I mean... In SQL using join we need to use on-clausule like:

```
select * from table_1 t1, table_2 t2 where t1.t2_id=t2.t1_id;
```

But I can't find information about it in API Criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From JPA 2.1 specification, chapter *4.4.5 Joins*:

> An inner join may be implicitly specified by the use of a cartesian
>   product in the `FROM` clause and a join condition in the `WHERE`
>   clause. In the absence of a join condition, this reduces to the
>   cartesian product.
>
> The main use case for this generalized style of join is when a join
>   condition does not involve a foreign key relationship that is mapped
>   to an entity relationship.
>
> Example:
>
> `SELECT c FROM Customer c, Employee e WHERE c.hatsize = e.shoesize`
>
> In general, use of this style of inner join (also referred to as
>   theta-join) is less typical than explicitly defined joins over
>   relationships.

Since JPQL is works the same way as Criteria API then equal restriction is needed in your query.